# How do I keep layer scale visibility when exporting a leaflet map with qgis2leaf?

Tags: qgis2leaf

I'm trying to export a leaflet map using qgid2leaf. Some of the map layers have a scaled visibility range. However on the leaflet map these layers show at all scales? Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented in the plugin ATM. You can either change the index.html and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017318/leaflet-remove-layer-if-zoom-level-greater-than-9) as a hint.

Or you can create an issue and we will try to solve this in a next release.
Or you can hire a developer to implement it for you in a given time.